# Freestanding wood frame inside masonry shell for noise?

Tags: architecture, noise

I'm a lay neighborhood advocate, not an engineer.

Proposed is a three-storey multi-family housing project adjacent to an airport. A concern is that noise pollution will create higher tenancy turnover, thereby diminishing rental income and possibly lead to negative social impacts.

What are state of the art noise suppression options in  architecture? Briefly reading online, it seems an ideal might be to have a freestanding wood frame building constructed inside a freestanding masonry shell, where the two shells connect only at window and door frames. Everywhere else would be either an air gap or sound-absorbing material.

But has this been successfully attempted, and if not, what is the most effective practical implementation of noise reduction?

Comment: State of the art passive noise suppression was a specialized foam in a specific wavy egg carton-ish (but not quite) shape last I checked.  Takes a couple feet of that stuff to zero out just about anything out there, but it's very effective even in lesser amounts.  How much space can you dedicate to noise suppression?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this veers into discriminatory language.

Comment: You don't think that the noise as observed from *outside* the dwelling will be grossly undesirable as well?

Comment: To clarify, the concern about "lower incomes and increasing crime" is from others in the neighborhood. I'm attempting to address the engineering-related aspect, in order to increase the supply of housing and thus make it more affordable for all.

Comment: The developer contends outside won't matter as long as inside is OK. Government officials are buying that logic but are not buying that inside can be made OK.

Comment: @Abel do you have a link describing that?

Comment: Just search for `Sound Absorbing Foam`.  Structures you find will all use the same principle to get you close and other (easier to manufacture) geometries, but the specific "state of the art geometry" I speak of is likely proprietary.